# Android WiFi direct doesn't show peers on android pie

Tags: java, android, p2p, wifi-direct

I find these changes on Wi-Fi Direct broadcasts on API 29
[WiFi Broadcasts](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes-all#wifi-direct-broadcasts).But I don't know how to make it work please help me

```
  myBroadcastReciever = new MyBroadcastReciever(p2pManager, channel,this, infoListener);
  myBroadcastReciever.setPeerListListener(peerListListener);

  IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
  intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);
  intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
  intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
  intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);

  registerReceiver(myBroadcastReciever, intentFilter);`
```

Comment: Please don't use `android-studio` tag if your question does not specifically deal with the IDE itself

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by allowing location on API 29,but that a strange thing from google why using location to make wifi/direct work.